# Change the visibilty of a div in PHP code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a div that contains a table and I set the visibility to hidden.I also have a button in my form and I want to set the visibility of my div to visible when button clicked in PHP part not in javascript or jquery part.

```
<div id="infoPart" style="visibility: hidden"></div>

<?php
//here I want to set the visibilty of div to visible and do some other tasks
  ?>
```

Comment: it is possible but this thing is refresh your page ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can print a **style** tag that overides the element's style.
The following code will make the div `#infoPart` visible

```
<div id="infoPart" style="visibility: hidden"></div>
<?php
//here I want to set the visibilty of div to visible and do some other tasks
echo '<style>#infoPart{visibility: visible !important;}</style>';
?>
```

Note that, we're using `!important` which means you cannot change the visibility later.

Comment: You shouldn't use `!important`. That will mean you cannot show the element later.

Comment: @vascowhite But, it does the job.

Comment: @Gavin Looks like `!important` is needed (http://jsfiddle.net/s4AmW/8/). Updated answer. @vascowhite Now, it works

Comment: `!important` is only needed in this case because this method isn't good. You shouldn't be echoing out CSS like this that changes an element's style right after you define its `style` property. If you do not define the element's visiblity in it's `style` property and only echo out the CSS below it, it will work fine. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/8KmQy/ BUT, he already said he'll use JavaScript/jQuery to show the DIV when a button is clicked, so JavaScript will be the best method to show the DIV, not CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing up concepts.

The PHP code is executed on the server. If you want to hide a div through php there is no need to use `visibility:hidden` - simple place the entire `<div>` within a php `if` block and skip it if it should be hidden.

To show it through php you would have to *reload the entire page* from the server. It is indeed possible and that is how web frameworks such as asp.net webforms works.

If you want good user experience you should definitely use a solution that handles the hiding and displaying in the browser, without the need for reloading the page from the server. PHP code can't be run in the browser, so you have to use JavaScript in that case. jQuery is a *JavaScript library* that makes it easier to manipulate the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

PHP cannot modify the source of a webpage with out refreshing the page. 
This is why we have JavaScript.

It seems your are doing something in the wrong order, if you have a reason for this , please explain why you think you need to do this

Comment: I think what you mean is "This is why we have JAVASCRIPT"

Answer (score 0):

You mention you're already using javascript, so you can just do this:

```
<?php
echo "<script> document.getElementById('infoPart').style.visibility='hidden'; </script>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to reload page if you want to do any change in PHP variable.

```
/*or any logic from button click*/
$flagToShow = (!isEmpty($_REQUEST['variable'])) ? $_REQUEST['variable']: "hidden"; 

 echo "<div id=\"infoPart\" style=\"visibility: {$flagToShow}\"></div>";
```

Reload is required because PHP statement is works on server side. Jquery and other javascript is work without reload because it works at client side.